# Is "код" the best way to translate "code"?

Tags: перевод, информатика

In the context of programming, is "код" the best way to translate "code"? (as a noun, not a verb)

Additional question: What is a good translation for "development"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Purely in the programming context: code = код, (software) development = разработка (программного обеспечения).

Comment: And colloquially "code" as a verb might be "кодить", as there are no direct translations of that verb into russian. The verb "писать" is also used, and is preferable in first person singular ("кодю" is ugly).

Comment: What would you mean by "ugly", @MigMit ?

Comment: Just that it sounds unnatural for a Russian. While being the only reasonable way to form first person singular of the verb "кодить". That's all.

Comment: @MigMit how about synonyms like `программировать` or `писать код`?

Comment: @UVV `программировать` is more broad, it includes designing the program; `писать код` is OK, but it's two words instead of one. So, if you need to translate the verb `code` in a context where colloquialisms are inappropriate, `писать код` is your best choice.

Comment: Topic Starter should also learn the word `говнокодить` :)

Answer (score 1):

A set of technical standards, GOST (Russian: ГОСТ), contains articles "Terms and definitions", where you'll find examples that illustrate the use of the word `код` as a single term:
[ГОСТ 19781-90](http://www.opengost.ru/iso/01_gosty/01040_gost_iso/0104035_gost_iso/1186-gost-19781-90-obespechenie-sistem-obrabotki-informacii-programmnoe.-terminy-i-opredeleniya.html) , [ГОСТ 19.101-77](http://protect.gost.ru/v.aspx?control=8&baseC=-1&page=0&month=-1&year=-1&search=&RegNum=1&DocOnPageCount=15&id=150791)

`Исходный код` has most likely become an idiom instead of `исходный текст`. It can be found in [ГОСТ Р 54593-2011](http://dlib.rsl.ru/loader/view/01005405118?get=pdf) in the domain of Open Source.

Within a book, you'll likely come across:
`исходный текст --> объектный код` = `source code --> object code`
rather than
`исходный код --> объектный код.`

In *informal* correspondence, reports, etc. in the domain of programming, the common term used is `код` for `source code.`